# How Do I Archive/Transfer Local Newsgroup From Windows Server 2003 (IIS) To A Ubuntu New Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ubuntu-10.04, nntp

I have some local newsgroups that are maintained on a windows 2003 server. That server is getting upgraded to 2008 or 2012, which don't support NNTP. I'd like to run a news server on an Ubuntu system and transfer the newsgroups to that system. How do I set up a newsgroup server on an Ubuntu 10.04 system and how do I populate the newsgroup with all of the messages currently on my Windows 2003 server?

Thanks in advance for suggestions and comments.